# implementing mapAsync in scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, semaphore, flatmap

I'm trying to implement a mapAsync method for general sequences. Somehow it works when used independently, but it doesn't work when used inside a `flatMap`. Example code

```scala
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}

object Test extends App {
  implicit class SeqWrapper[+A, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](underlying: M[A]) {
    def mapAsyncSequential[B](
      f: A ⇒ Future[B]
    )(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Future[B]], B, M[B]]): Future[M[B]] = {
      underlying
        .foldLeft(Future.successful(cbf())) { (fr, fa) ⇒
          for {
            r ← fr
            a ← f(fa)
          } yield r += a
        }
        .map(_.result())
    }

    def mapAsyncParallel[B](
      f: A ⇒ Future[B]
    )(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Future[B]], B, M[B]]): Future[M[B]] = {
      underlying
        .map(f)
        .foldLeft(Future.successful(cbf())) { (fr, fb) ⇒
          for {
            r ← fr
            b ← fb
          } yield (r += b)
        }
        .map(_.result())
    }

    def mapAsync[B](
      concurrentInstances: Int
    )(f: A ⇒ Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Future[B]], B, M[B]]): Future[M[B]] = {
      val sem = new Semaphore(concurrentInstances)

      // It still spawns n threads. Just throttles the start of the actual operation.
      // It is based on semaphore, so threads are not busy-waiting.
      // Only the execution of the operation is delayed.
      // For ForkJoinPool execution-contexts it is fine, as it will spawn more threads when needed.
      // Using synchronized on the local variable, so that it's independent when used in multiple-threads.
      // Also, this is not super efficient, as it launches 3 threads for one element, but as said above,
      // it's fine for fork-join-pools.
      def throttled(current: A): Future[B] = Future {
        println("acquiring")
        sem.acquire()
        println("acquired")
      }.flatMap { _ ⇒
        println("operation")
        f(current).andThen {
          case _ ⇒
            println("release")
            sem.release()
        }
      }

      mapAsyncParallel(throttled)
    }
  }
  implicit class FutureValueProvider[T](f: Future[T]) {
    def futureValue: T = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
  }
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
  import system.dispatcher
  try {
    def f: Future[List[Int]] = {
      List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).mapAsync(4) { scope =>
        Future.successful(scope)
      }
    }
    println(f.futureValue) // works
    println(Future.successful(1).flatMap(_ => f).futureValue) // gets stuck
  } finally system.terminate()
}
```

The first operation works with the following output

```
acquiring
acquiring
acquired
acquiring
acquired
operation
operation
acquiring
acquired
acquiring
acquired
operation
operation
release
release
acquired
release
release
operation
release
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

But the second one gets stuck with the following output

```
acquiring
acquired
acquiring
acquired
acquiring
acquired
acquiring
acquired
acquiring
```

Why would that happen? What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not closely familiar with the Akka dispatcher, but playing around with your code I observed that keeping that as the execution context you will see that this works as long as the items in the list are fewer or equal than the parallelism specified in your `mapAsync` function.

Comment: Switching to a work-stealing pool or a fixed thread pool with more than 1 thread makes this work. Switching to a fixed thread pool with a single thread causes a deadlock, as the first task comes in, acquires the only permit, and leaves no thread available for any callback to be dispatched on, including the one that `flatMap`s the release. I suspect something along these lines is what happens by using the actor system's dispatcher.

Comment: I would probably shy away from using low-level locking mechanisms within `Future`s, as they can interact with the resource managed by the `ExecutionService` in ways that are difficult to predict and reason about. Furthermore, this also probably works against the idea of using a `Future` as an abstraction over the underlying expensive OS threads (assuming you are using OS threads, which might become less of a problem in the future thanks to virtual threads).

Comment: To add to the above: blocking tasks in Future require `blocking { }` to inform execution context that blocking needs to be handled.

Comment: All of you are correct, and adding blocking around the acquire block made it work now :-)